# disappearing dataframes using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, in my fonction i create a randome list of size 60 a 100 times contaning the indexes of a voting station (not the dataframes indexes but a "homemade" one in the Dataframe. "NBURO" is where i keep my homemade index. df is the dataframe i am trying to sample

```
        
        x = df["NBURO"].values.tolist()
        SI = rd.sample(x,n)      
        Smp = df.loc[df["NBURO"].isin(SI)]
```

The length of SI is always 60 but when i do  `smp.describe()`  the count is not always a multiple of 60, it varies between 60 and 55 but i imagine it can go lower.
I don't see why Smp is not complete.

**EDIT :**

When i turn SI into a set it does, infact, not have a length of 60. I don't understand how `rd.sample()` works apparently

Comment: Could be duplicates exist in SI?

Comment: @JasonChia that's what i thought but this is what rd.sample does:

"Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set. Used for random sampling without replacement."

Comment: Yeah, rd.sample random samples without replacement. Meaning that if you have a list of [1,2,1,2,3] you could sample n samples from the list with repeats as there are multiples of them in the list. rd.sample simply samples without replacement from your list but if there are duplicates in the list there could be duplicates in your sample. Does changing your list to a set fix your issue? You should confirm by checking the length of your 'set' and list to determine how many duplicates you have.